# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'salt'

Tags: python, passwords

I am learning python and was working on one of the early exercises and followed the instructions and created everything and placed the dictionary file and pointed the script to run on my /etc/passwd file but keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'salt'
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
  import crypt
def testPass(cryptPass):
    salt = cryptPass[0:2]
    dictFile = open('dictionary.txt','r')
    for word in dictFile.readlines():
        word = word.strip('\n')
        cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word.salt)
        if (cryptWord == cryptPass):
            print "[+] Found Password: "+word+"\n"
            return
    print "[-] Password Not Found.\n"
    return
def main():
    passFile = open('/etc/passwd')
    for line in passFile.readlines():
        if ":" in line:
            user = line.split(":")[0]
            cryptPass = line.split(":")[1].strip(' ')
            print "[*] Cracking Password for: " +user
            testPass(cryptPass)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a `salt` *attribute* on the string `word`:

```
cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word.salt)
#                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

You probably meant to use a comma instead, to pass in the name `salt` as a separate argument:

```
cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word, salt)
```

Comment: That indeed was the answer, thank you very much :)